# Distributed files using GenericOptionsParser and ToolRunner

Tags: hadoop, distributed-caching, toolrunner

I used to run hadoop mapreduce using (This uses GenericOptionsParser)

`hadoop jar app.jar app -files /home/some/file#file`

However in the recent version of hadoop I am getting

`Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.`

So how to implement `-files` option to share among all mapreduce nodes using ToolRunner?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently previous ones have been deprecated...

this is what I did...

`import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
.
.
.
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
.
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "appname");
job.setJarByClass(appname.class);
.
.
job.addCacheFile(new URI("/file/in/hdfs/APP/appfile#appfile"));
.
.`